Cycle off a voltage at a specific amplitude height [revised]
Currently, I'm trying to simulate a patient- mechanical ventilator interaction in LTspice. Therefore, the mechanical ventilator should be on when a certain pressure drop is reached and should cycle off when a percentage after the peak flow is reached, commonly 80%. Now I'm trying to simulate this in LTspice, but I'm running into some problems with the cycle off.
The simulation circuit (fig 1) has a voltage source of a sine wave, which represents the pressure the patient would produce. Furthermore, there is a switch and a voltage source Pinsp (Inspiratory pressure). This inspiratory pressure should only be applied to the circuit during 'inspiration'. It starts when the sine wave transitions from negative to positive (zero crossing point) and should turn off when the 80% value after the amplitude has been reached. See figure 2 for the wanted output.
In the real simulation, the amplitude off the sine wave changes per period. Therefore, the value the ventilator cycles off at should also change, how can I do this?



it is unclear how the circuit should behave ... please draw the input waveform and the expected output

Sounds like you need a Schmitt Trigger with adjustable hysteresis.

And how would I implement a Schmitt Trigger with a varying amplitude?

I could post a Fuller answer tomorrow if desired. A microcontroller would do this with ease and cost very little but may be undesirable in this application. The 80% falling edge turn off can be easily achieved by using a peak hold to determine the maximum value of the sine wave and a 80% divider to set the turn off point. The peakhold voltage is reset on each cycle as the system transits through zero rising. You need memory to allow the voltage to rise past the turn off point but to then turn off on the falling edge. ||

Since I'm a graduate biomedical engineer and my forté is not in the electrical engineering field, I would appreciate a more elaborate answer.

You could detect a change in direction of the input sinusoid, using a differentiator. The derivative of \$sin(x)\$ is zero when it changes direction, at its peak and valley points, and it becomes negative immediately following the peak. A differentiator can be made with a simple RC high-pass filter:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The resistive element of the differentiator here is actually composed of two resistors, to bias its output so that it is centered around +2.5V, mid-way between the supply rails of 0V and +5V. That output is compared against a fixed +2.5V by the comparator.
When the input signal at IN begins its downwards excursion (immediately following an input peak), its derivative at X drops below +2.5V, and the comparator output OUT goes high. OUT returns low when the input begins its upwards excursion.
This behaviour does not depend on the amplitude or frequency of signal, only the sign of its derivative, and so even if input amplitude changes over time, the circuit correctly identifies input peaks:

You should probably introduce some positive feedback for a little hysteresis, to improve immunity to a noisy input signal, but my aim here was to make the above derivative suggestion, not produce a finished design.

Thank you for your response. However, I'm not looking for the peaks of the sine wave to start the switch. The switch should start when the sine is positive and should end at 80% of the peak value after the peak, the black asterix in my edit. Is this possible with a differentiator or should I use something else?

@Stijn I think you should rewrite your question, so it's easier to understand. Show us a graph, hand-drawn is fine, on which you show the interval within which you want something "on". I misunderstood your graph with the red lines, so it'll need to be better than that.

@Stijn Now that the question is closed, your best bet to get it reopened, and attract answers, is to draw the graph showing the "on" region, as I suggested.

thank you for the feedback. Hopefully the graph is more clear now otherwise I would like to hear from you

@Stijn I see where I got confused. I would ask for: "Output goes high when input rises through zero volts, and returns low when input falls again through 80% of its peak value."
